# Get a control's original frame for both portrait and landscape

Tags: ios, swift, frame

I am working on an application that has different UI constraints and control positions for portrait and landscape.  These are all done on the storyboard.  In addition to this, I am repositioning controls based on a user shutting off one of the controls.  I am doing this by grabbing the frame for each of the controls in viewDidLoad.  Once I have these values, then it is easy to reposition the controls and restore them to what they should be when unhidden.  The thing is that I need all of the frames for both portrait and landscape.  That way I can do the repositioning regardless of orientation.

How can I get the control positioning information for both portrait and landscape when coming through viewDidLoad?  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

After adding constraints to a view, and the view readjusting its position and size according to device size and orientation. This readjusting of the view size is done in the method `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, which is called after `viewDidAppear`.
If you can log out the positions and size of the control in this method, you will get the updated (size and position as it is seen in the device).

But this method is called multiple times after `viewDidAppear`, so if you want to add anything i recommend adding the control in `viewDidLoad` and then updating the position in this method.

Comment: This definitely gives me some ideas on how to approach this.  I will respond back after I've had a chance to try this tonight.

Answer (score 0):

After working with this a bit more, I came up with this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var pButtonFrame: CGRect!
    var lButtonFrame: CGRect!

    @IBOutlet weak var testButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "screenRotated", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func screenRotated() {
        //Set this only once, the first time the orientation is used.
        if lButtonFrame == nil && UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation)
        {
            lButtonFrame = testButton.frame
        }
        else if pButtonFrame == nil && UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation)
        {
            pButtonFrame = testButton.frame
        }
    }
}
```

I set up a test button and positioned it using constraints on the storyboard.  I added an observer to `NSNotificationCenter` to watch for screen rotation.  I'm storing the frames for each of the orientations in `CGRect` variables.  By checking each of the variables for nil, I can ensure that they only get set once, before I have done any modifications to the screen.  That way, I can restore the values to their originals, if needed.  I can set up the showing and hiding of controls here, or in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var pButtonFrame: CGRect!
    var lButtonFrame: CGRect!

    @IBOutlet weak var btntest: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        screenRotate()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func screenRotate() {
        //Set this only once, the first time the orientation is used.
        if lButtonFrame == nil && UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation)
        {
            lButtonFrame = btntest.frame
        }
        else if pButtonFrame == nil && UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation)
        {
            pButtonFrame = btntest.frame
        }
    }
}
```